# Add parameter to href using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that looks like this.

```
<a id="link" href="../customer_record/?id=1&customer_id=2"></a>
```

I also have an input box as the following.

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

I am trying to get jQuery to add a parameter to the link as the user types into the input box.

```
// add search to link
$('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    var href = $('#link').attr("href");
    var data = $(this).val();
  $('#link').attr('href', href + '&search-string=' + data);
});
```

I don't think I am far away but I just can't get it to work.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You're reinventing forms. Don't do that. Just use a form. `<form action="../customer_record/"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="2"><input type="text" name="search-string"><button>Search</button></form>`

Comment: every key press you add `'&search-string=' + data` to the end. If does not keep updating it....

Comment: you just need to close the anchor tag(`</a>`)

Comment: @Robin that is not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the URL query string with [URLSearchParams: set() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) of [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API). See the following example.

```js
// add search to link
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  var href = $('#link')[0].href;
  var urlHref = new URL(href);
  urlHref.searchParams.set('search-string', $(this).val());
  $('#link').attr("href", urlHref);
  console.log($('#link').attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="../customer_record/?id=1&customer_id=2">link</a>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Store the original href in a variable
    var originalHref = $('#link').attr("href");

    $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        var newHref = updateQueryStringParameter(originalHref, 'search-string', data);
        $('#link').attr('href', newHref);
        console.log($('#link').attr("href"));
    });

    function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
        var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
        var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
        
        if (uri.match(re)) {
            return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        } else {
            return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="../customer_record/?id=1&customer_id=2">test</a>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

u almost there

```
      <a id="link" href="../customer_record/?id=1&customer_id=2"></a>
<input type="text" id="search">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Store the original href in a variable
    var originalHref = $('#link').attr("href");

    $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        var newHref = updateQueryStringParameter(originalHref, 'search-string', data);
        $('#link').attr('href', newHref);
    });

    function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
        var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
        var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
        
        if (uri.match(re)) {
            return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        } else {
            return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does this code even run? Your functions are not closed. Wont the link be triggered when you click in the #search input? Why not make a working snippet of this so readers can test it?

Comment: Protip: don't use a variable to store the original URL - what if you want to apply this to 2 links? 200 links?    `$(".link").each(function() { $(this).data("original-url", $(this).attr("href")) })`